# Memory allocation in a fixed point algorithm

Tags: algorithm, julia

I need to find the fixed point of a function f. The algorithm is very simple:

1. Given X, compute f(X)
2. If ||X-f(X)|| is lower than a certain tolerance, exit and return X, 
   otherwise set X equal to f(X) and go back to 1.

I'd like to be sure I'm not allocating memory for a new object at every iteration

For now, the algorithm looks like this:

```
iter1 = function(x::Vector{Float64})
    for iter in 1:max_it
        oldx = copy(x)
        g1(x)
        delta = vnormdiff(x, oldx, 2)
        if delta < tolerance
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Here `g1(x)` is a function that sets `x` to `f(x)`

But it seems this loop allocates a new vector at every loop (see below).

Another way to write the algorithm is the following:

```
iter2 = function(x::Vector{Float64})
    oldx = similar(x)
    for iter in 1:max_it
        (oldx, x) = (x, oldx)
        g2(x, oldx)
        delta = vnormdiff(oldx, x, 2)
        if delta < tolerance
            break
        end
    end
end
```

where `g2(x1, x2)` is a function that sets `x1` to `f(x2)`.

Is thi the most efficient and natural way to write this kind of iteration problem?

Edit1: timing shows that the second code is faster:

```
using NumericExtensions
max_it = 1000
tolerance = 1e-8
max_it = 100

g1 = function(x::Vector{Float64}) 
    for i in 1:length(x)
        x[i] = x[i]/2
    end
end

g2 = function(newx::Vector{Float64}, x::Vector{Float64}) 
    for i in 1:length(x)
        newx[i] = x[i]/2
    end
end

x = fill(1e7, int(1e7))
@time iter1(x)
# elapsed time: 4.688103075 seconds (4960117840 bytes allocated, 29.72% gc time)
x = fill(1e7, int(1e7))
@time iter2(x)
# elapsed time: 2.187916177 seconds (80199676 bytes allocated, 0.74% gc time)
```

Edit2: using `copy!`

```
iter3 = function(x::Vector{Float64})
    oldx = similar(x)
    for iter in 1:max_it
        copy!(oldx, x)
        g1(x)
        delta = vnormdiff(x, oldx, 2)
        if delta < tolerance
            break
        end
    end
end
x = fill(1e7, int(1e7))
@time iter3(x)
# elapsed time: 2.745350176 seconds (80008088 bytes allocated, 1.11% gc time)
```

Comment: Is the first time I hear from this language, so probably I am wrong. The initial algorithm you describe seems to be a good candidate for the compiler to optimize it. In other languages, sometimes making the simplest code gets better results. And with primitives even more. is julia lang so different?

Comment: I don't think Julia is particularly different, I'm just not a very knowledgeable  programmer ;)

Comment: You may want `copy!` instead of `copy`. The `@time` macro will tell you how much memory your code allocates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think replacing the following lines in the first code

```
for iter = 1:max_it
    oldx = copy( x )
    ...
```

by

```
oldx = zeros( N )
for iter = 1:max_it
    oldx[:] = x    # or copy!( oldx, x )
    ...
```

will be more efficient because no array is allocated. Also, the code can be made more efficient by writing for-loops explicitly. This can be seen, for example, from the following comparison

```
function test()
    N = 1000000

    a = zeros( N )
    b = zeros( N )

    @time c = copy( a )

    @time b[:] = a

    @time copy!( b, a )

    @time \
    for i = 1:length(a)
        b[i] = a[i]
    end

    @time \
    for i in eachindex(a)
        b[i] = a[i]
    end
end

test()
```

The result obtained with Julia0.4.0 on Linux(x86_64) is

```
elapsed time: 0.003955609 seconds (7 MB allocated)
elapsed time: 0.001279142 seconds (0 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.000836167 seconds (0 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 1.19e-7 seconds (0 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 1.28e-7 seconds (0 bytes allocated)
```

It seems that `copy!()` is faster than using `[:]` in the left-hand side,
though the difference becomes marginal in repeated calculations (there seems to be
some overhead for the first `[:]` calculation). Btw, the last example using `eachindex()` is very convenient for looping over multi-dimensional arrays.

Similar comparison can be made for `vnormdiff()`,  where use of `norm( x - oldx )` etc is slower than an explicit loop for vector norm, because the former allocates one temporary array for `x - oldx`.

Comment: Thanks!  I tested this solution, and it turns out that your solution is nearly as fast as the ideal implementation. However, I still find it somewhat inelegant to copy a vector at each loop while, in principle, I could just switch their name. Does that make sense?

Comment: Following Vincent Zoonekynd comment, `copy!(oldx, x)` has the same performance than `oldx[:] = x` (but looks clearer I think)

Comment: @Matthew I did not know `copy!()` (thank you @Vincent Zoonekynd), so added another comparison with it. It seems `copy!()` is fastest.

Comment: @Matthew Switching the names of two vectors is straight-forward, e.g., `tmp = x ; x = y ; y = tmp` or  `( x, y ) = ( y, x ) `. Because  this is just a copy of reference, no array allocation occurs so very efficient.